Are movie identification questions allowed again?
Movie identification questions were banned about at the end of 2017 on this site. I answered a lot of these questions back then, but after the ban a lot of my old answers were closed/deleted/not allowed/disappeared (whatever the proper term is for that) and my points decreased as well due to this. But today I have just noticed that a lot of old identification questions are appearing again and my old answers and points are also restored. So, what is happening? Are movie identification questions allowed again on this site? Thank you and Happy Holidays to everyone!

Yes, see the [meta] posts: What does the community want to do with identification questions? and Please unlock, undelete, & reopen closed ID questions in line with our community consensus

galacticninja, thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with other parts of the site, so I was not aware of those other threads about this topic you pointed me at. Thank you again.
